# Who would cross the Bridge of Death / Must answer me / These questions three:

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

[image]

Oh, Holy Grail, thou art puny and small
When compared to the treasure I want most of all.
It can sometimes—not always—be found in receptacles.
So read, mark my words. If need, use your spectacles.

It's found here and there in its lair of communities.
Narcissistic, self-righteous—but not with impunity.
It's the best, I believe; I contend my contention.
Perhaps due to its color, it draws envy, dissension.

While it's crooked by nature and seemingly dangled,
It rewards one who answers when questions are angled.
In the instance at hand, if yours warms me the most,
You can add to your collection and of it you may boast.

Now just answer these five (three!) questions:

> What...is your name?
>
> What...is your quest?
>
> What...is your favorite color?

Comment: Blue. No — it’s yellow!!!! Aaaaaaahhhh!

Comment: Look! It's the man from scene 24!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What... is your name?

> generalcrispy. Hi. :)

What... is your quest?

> The **accepted answer**, denoted by the checkmark.

What... is your favorite color?

> The one which draws envy. **Green.**

Comment: But what is the maximum lifting weight of an average European swallow, eh?

Comment: You know much that is hidden, O generalcrispy. Your sweet, juicy, green reward is on its way.